# Can't display retrieved data from SQLite , Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I am developing an android app in Xamarin and I have a problem when reading all data from specific column in sqlite database. This is my code in LinesData: SqliteHelper class :

```
public IList<Lines> getAllCities()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.ReadableDatabase;

            ICursor c = db.Query("Lines", null, null, null, null, null, null);

            var cities = new List<Lines>();
            while (c.MoveToNext())
            {
                cities.Add(new Lines
                {
                    SecondName = c.GetString(2)
                });
            }
            c.Close();
            db.Close();

            return cities;
        }
```

This is my code to retrieve and store this data. I think that there is a problem here:

```
ListView listViewCity = new ListView(this);
            LinesData o = new LinesData(this);
            IList<Lines> cities = new List<Lines>();
            cities = o.getAllCities();
            String[] items = cities.Cast<String>().ToArray();
            listViewCity.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
```

(this,Resource.Layout.cityListView, items);

I think I haven't cast the list into array correctly . I am looking forward to any help! :)

Comment: Maybe there is a mistake with query and the line  SecondName = c.GetString(2) too.. I am new to this so maybe I didn;t understand this very well

Comment: What does the Lines class look like?